# Отслеживание кода в отладчике

Tags: кодировка, xdebug, php

При просмотре скрипта в отладчике (xDebug) вижу подобные строки:

```
$day /* string */ = Р”РµРЅСЊ (русские буквы)<br>
```

Все файлы сохраняю в коде Utf-8. При ANSI - все нормально.
Пока еще не знаю где, что изменить? Сохранение должны оставаться в utf-8!

Comment: скорее всего, отладчик xDebug не поддерживает нормально юникод. А то, что он отображает - это и есть юникод, просто отображенный как ansi.

Comment: > отладчик xDebug не поддерживает нормально юникод

Еще как поддерживает, смотрите настройки той среды из которой идет процесс отладки.

Comment: я немножко погуглил и увидел, что подобные проблемы наблюдаются в нетбинсе и эклипсе.

Comment: Бобы - борода. В phpstorm все гуд.

Comment: В phpstorm 9 то же самое.